# OpenOfficeOrg Calc always prints in Landscape mode

Tags: printing, openoffice.org

So for some strange reason today anything I print in OpenOffice Calc comes out in Landscape mode.

I have tried the following:

- Set the print job from OO Calc to portrait (prints out in landscape)
- Tried opening a brand new file which by default is set to portrait (prints out in landscape)
- Setting the default printer job orientation to portrait (prints out in landscape)
- Print from gedit in portrait mode (prints out in portrait)

Not sure what else to try. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using LibreOffice, so things might be slightly different, but I've had this problem before with Calc. Go to the "Format" menu, then click on "Page". You'll find a setting for orientation on the "Page" tab. Set it to Landscape, then do the same for your printer settings.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Go to format like "ok" said and to Page. Then look at portrait and landscape, mine was set to the opposite proportions. Write down the #'s, mine says 8.26x11.69. DON'T select landscape, that will show your pages as landscape and print them that way, so if you go onto a second page but shouldn't, it will split it up. DO enter the dimensions as they should be shown for portrait it should be width - 8.26" x 11.69" then make sure it altered the number for the landscape options as well.

Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I discovered that printer settings had 2 sheets per page set. I changed it to 1 and it finally did the trick.