# Export landscape PDF from LibreOffce Calc

Tags: libreoffice

Even though I set the page format to Landscape (through menu Format => Page, tab Page), when I export a PDF (through menu File => Export as PDF) it's still portrait.  What could be the cause of that?

A seemingly [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107686/openofficeorg-calc-always-prints-in-landscape-mode) was asked, but my question is

- about exporting PDF, not print and
- assumes that orientation is already correctly set.

LibreOffice version is 5.1.4.2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out that the page orientation has to be set for each sheet individually, which I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Note that this is set through Format -> Page Style -> Page / Paper Format -> Orientation, with the particular sheet selected